# Adding to ascii code during for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

This is probably a simple fix but I can't seem to solve it.

I am trying to add an integer to the ascii value of characters during a for loop.

It is giving me the error that the program expects a variable rather than a value. How can I do what I am trying to do here?

Here is the code:

```
public boolean toggleEncryption(){
    if(encrypted == false){
        for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++){
            if(sentence.charAt(i) >= 65 && sentence.charAt(i) <= 90){
                int x = (int)sentence.charAt(i);
                x += key;
                while(x > 90){
                    x = x - 26;
                }
                sentence.charAt(i) += (char)x;
            }
        }
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

the line `sentence.charAt(i) += (char)x;` is not working for me

Comment: If `sentence` is a String, then it is immutable, and thus you cannot change it.

Comment: I am actually trying to figure that out right now, I dont use this site a whole lot. Where do I click to accept your answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple:

```
sentence.charAt(i) += (char)x;
```

You wrongly assume that `charAt()` gives you a "left hand side" thingy. In other words: something that you can **assign** a value to; like a variable.

But this is not possible: `charAt()` returns an char value; that represents the char within the string at that index.

It does **not** give you something that allows you to manipulate the string itself! Strings are immutable; you can't use `charAt()` to modify its content!

In other words; you can do this:

```
char c = 'a';
c += 'b';
```

but you can't use `charAt()` to achieve the same!

Thus, in order to make your code work, you have to build a **new** string, like:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(sentence.length());
for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
  if(sentence.charAt(i) >= 65 && sentence.charAt(i) <= 90){
    int x = (int)sentence.charAt(i);
    x += key;
    while(x > 90){
      x = x - 26;
    }
    builder.append(sentence.charAt(i) + (char)x));
  } else {
    builder.append(sentence.charAt(i)); 
  }
}
```

(disclaimer: I just wrote down the above code; there might be typos or little bugs in there; it is meant to be "pseudo code" to get you going!)

Beyond that: I find the name of that method; and how it deals with that boolean field ... a bit confusing. You see, if encryption is **true** ... the method does nothing?! Then it doesn't "toggle" anything. Thus that name is really misleading resp. not matching what your code is doing!

Comment: That makes sense, what should I use in order to achieve what I am going for?

Comment: Plus: I put in some more comments; hope they are helpful.

Comment: I ended up converting to a char array but your answer helped me solve my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here `charAt(i)` returns a char:

```
sentence.charAt(i) += (char)x;
```

1) You cannot assign a character to a value but you can do it to a variable.

2) Even if you used a variable such as

```
char tempChar = sentence.charAt(i);
```

You cannot do then :

```
tempChar += (char)x;
```

As you cannot increment `(+=)` a character with another character.